# How to overcome the labels overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a sticky labels on the extreme endpoints of the charts, and the labels are displayed at the correct points. 
please have a look at here:

[image]

And the respective fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/11/)

That is ok, but now consider the series array to be

```
series: [{
                name: 'CPM',
                data: [600, 110, 235, 369, 340,371, 322, 300],
                color: 'rgb(87, 188, 0)'
            }, {
                name: 'IMPS',
                data: [300, 160, 269, 60, 165, 371, 322, 300],
                color: 'rgb(213, 156, 72)'
            }, {
                name: 'SPEND',
                data: [100, 100, 215, 120, 150, 200, 326, 300],
                color: 'rgb(12, 170, 226)'
            }]
```

If you consider this array, the `data` array inside each object ends with value **300**, in this case the chart will be drawn like [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/12/) , Like wise if all the starting elements of the data array, are also same then again the overlapping happens at the being.

Can we achieve some thing like

[image]

As you can see the right side of the image above is place above the other labels so as to avoid overlapping,

I need to achieve the same thing. Can you guys please help me.

Comment: So you need to detect overlapping rects on a chart. Where is the problem? You need some algorithm for that? See my old demo for similar issue with dataLabels: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/

Comment: @PawełFus, hey thanks for the reference, actually I saw your response in the morning itself, but after experimenting so much, I could not able to fix my problem, So it would be great if you can debug my code a little. and give me some more clue, Its my extreme request

Comment: This is what I would try: `a)` render one label for each sides, `b)` try to render second label, and if overlaps, render above/below first label `c)` do the same as in b), so try to render next label, check if overlaps first or second label etc. etc.

Comment: @PawełFus, dude thanks for the clue, will try this. Can you please just have a look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658332/highcharts-custom-display-of-tooltips-based-on-data-series-values , just help me in whatever points you can