# Highcharts Custom display of tooltips, based on data series values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I could explain better if you can focus on the image attached here:
[image]

1. Can the hover line height be shown only up to the max line height (Please see the image below)
2. I do not want to show the hover values for first and last week. (I mean on hover of 'week 0', I do not want to show the hover boxes, same as for 'week 7')
3. Can I set the floor and ceiling for the each series data, Some thing like

   series: [{
           name: 'CPM',
           data: [5,524,4,1,4,1,3,20,3],
           color: 'rgb(87, 188, 0)'
           //floor: 5,
           //ceiling: 524,
       },{ ....}
   }]

Is there any such floor/min and max/ceil for the each data set.

Such that the other two series data gets visible in the chart. please refer this fiddle

How to show All Data Series Fiddle  jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/21/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Could you show jsFiddle what is wrong? It's a little not clear for me.
2. In `tooltip.formatter` check `this.x` and return `false` when tooltip shouldn't be displayed.
3. Well, you can set that options, but it won't do anything.

Your image is saying something really different than `2)` .. to remove that vertical line, just disable `tooltip.crosshairs`.

To change order of points, you need to use `tooltip.formatter` - sort points descending and return formatter string.

References:

- [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)
- [`tooltip.crosshairs`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.crosshairs)